# Lightbox content appears on page

Tags: jquery, css, featherlight.js

I'm trying to set up a few lightboxes on a website and it's my first time working with [featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/).

Under [Installation](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#installation) it says to link to jQuery, as well as featherlight.js and featherlight.css

Under [Usage](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#usage) it says that this link should open the content in a lightbox:

```html
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
<div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>
```

It seems to work, except the `div` appears on the page even before the button is clicked. I don't see anything about adding manual CSS/jQuery to override this, but maybe I'm missing something?

I've included a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5p506at0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [demo page](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) the technique you are using is also used. The difference is that they give their lightbox div the class `lightbox` and then set that class to `display: none` so your code would look like this:

```css
.lightbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.5.0/release/featherlight.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.5.0/release/featherlight.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
<div id="mylightbox" class="lightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>
```

**Explanation:** `display: none` is still actually present on the displayed lightbox (check with dev tools). It just doesn't have priority (which it would have if you used id selectors in your css).

Comment: I like this solution. Nice and simple and doesn't require containers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do something like this

```
<div id="lightboxes">
  <div id="mylightbox">This div will be opened in a lightbox</div>
</div>
```

Then just set the lightboxes div to display:none in your css

```
#lightboxes{
  display: none;
}
```

The plugin basically pulls the div you specify and duplicates it for a lightbox, so as long as you aren't hiding what you're cloning itself you shouldn't have any problems, even if its wrapper is hidden.